# Install Kannel on amazon EC2 server

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kannel

I am trying to set up a SMS service in my amazon EC2 server. 
I have been searching for an already build in service to send SMS but anyone is free, so i found Kannel and decided to try it. I came with the next questions:

Is it possible to send SMS from my ubuntu server to a celphone number using Kannel?

Does amazon EC2 service allows the SMS gateaway?

Is there any tutorial to install and configure Kannel on my ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have access to a telecom operators SMS system, you probably wont be able to use Kannel on EC2. Without access to an SMS system, you will need to use a supported phone device, which would would be impossible on EC2.

Some providers have an Email to SMS gateway. Addresses are often in some form of @provider.com. You can usually send messages this way for free. But you will have to research on each provider and how the email is set up.

Twilio and other services are going to be the easiest option to use in sending SMS messages.

Comment: Thats why amazon haz SNS service